# Error due to stdlib.h file IAR

Tags: c, stdio, iar, stm32f4discovery

I am using IAR Workbench for programming my stm32f4 Discovery board and am having trouble using functions like malloc from stdlib.h file which is present in this path: IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\arm\inc\c. Immediately after I include  and try to compile the program, I get a few error messages as follows:

> Error[Pe040]: expected an identifier C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\arm\inc\c\stdlib.h 97
>
> Error[Pe018]: expected a ")" C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\arm\inc\c\stdlib.h 97

However, when I am including `stdio.h` from the same location, I seem to be facing no issues. Could someone please let me know what I could be missing.

Comment: Can you please try  to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the errors you have? Maybe you have some error *before* you include that header file?

Comment: Share your include. Using "" or <>? Have a look in the headerfile, if there is a failure. Include paths are already known in the project (compiler/ linker) ?
By the way you should not use functions like malloc on embedded hardware.

Comment: the includes are `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` Using `stdio` isn't posing an issue. Only `stdlib` has a problem which I don't seem to realise why. Which equivalent of malloc should I be using for embedded hardware @Miguel13366?

Comment: @smyslov: If you don`t use an RTOS it is not casual to allocate memory dynamically on embedded hardware. I do not know your application, so i can not say, how to solve it in an other way. 
Do you have your problem only with malloc or even other commands? Is malloc defined there? You should post the file, where the problem occurs as @Joachim Pileborg says.

Comment: what is at line 97 in the stdlib.h file?